# How to display multidimensional API response in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, api

I am new in Django and I am trying to learn this framework.
I am trying to display the individual data from an API response.
From my views.py, I am passing order in a context.

```
order = response.json()['order']
return render(request, 'orders.html', {'order': order})
```

I need to display fulfillment_date and fulfillment_status

These are the tags I have tried on my frontend.

`{{ order.order_date }}` is working
`{{ order.fulfillments }}` is also working

But these are not working.

```
{{ order.fulfillments.fulfillment_date }}
{{ order.fulfillments[0].fulfillment_date }}
{{ order.fulfillments[0][0] }}
{{ order.fulfillments.['fulfillment_date'] }}
```

Thanks!

API response:

````
    "order": {
        "order_date": "2022-01-09T00:00:00",
        "order_name": null,
        "checkout_token": null,
        "payment_method": null,
        "total_price": null,
        "subtotal_price": null,
        "currency": null,
        "landing_site_url": null,
        "source": "orders_api_v3",
        "payment_status": null,
        "cancellation": null,
        "customer": {
            "external_id": "111222",
            "first_name": "First Name",
            "last_name": "Last Name",
            "email": "newnew@newnew.com",
            "phone_number": null,
            "accepts_email_marketing": null,
            "accepts_sms_marketing": null,
            "custom_properties": null
        },
        "billing_address": null,
        "shipping_address": null,
        "custom_properties": null,
        "fulfillments": [
            {
                "fulfillment_date": "2022-01-09T00:00:00",
                "status": "success",
                "shipment_info": {
                    "shipment_status": null,
                    "tracking_company": null,
                    "tracking_url": null,
                    "tracking_number": null
                },
                "fulfilled_items": [
                    {
                        "external_product_id": "223553388",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ],
                "external_id": "112121212"
            }
        ],
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": 5554786884,
                "created_at": "2022-01-10T03:59:28",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-10T03:59:28",
                "quantity": 1,
                "total_price": null,
                "subtotal_price": null,
                "coupon_code": null,
                "custom_properties": null,
                "product_id": 303170668,
                "external_product_id": "223553388"
            }
        ],
        "id": 2824686328,
        "created_at": "2022-01-10T03:59:28",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-10T03:59:28",
        "store_id": "1111",
        "external_id": "112121212"
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In template we don't use `[0]` to get first value of list, use `.0`.

```
{{ order.fulfillments.0.fulfillment_date }}
```